# Is this battery compatible with the Node MCU ESP8266?

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

Is this [battery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N74S3LO) compatible with this [NodeMCU ESP8266](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B010O1G1ES)
?

More details; it was recommended to use this [page](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_2_7?tag=shrikant06-20&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=3.7v%20lipo%20battery&sprefix=3.7v%20li%2Caps%2C573&crid=3EZ5X0GQYE3Z0&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3A3.7v%20lipo%20battery) to get a battery to power the Node ESP8266 but I'm not sure which models are compatible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @gre_gor: I agree. Can the question be moved to a different Stack Exchange where it better belongs, such as electronics.stackexchange.com or arduino.stackexchange?

Comment: yes, you can use about anything with a dc-dc switch mode buck/boost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are 3.7V batteries, and the ESP8266 requires exactly 3.3V. That mean you need a voltage regulator to step down the voltage.

But watch out: Most common voltage regulators have a **dropout voltage** of 1.0V or more (including the [AMS1117](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf) regulator on your board). That mean *the regulator itself consumes at least 1.0V of the input voltage*.

In our example, 3.7V - 1.0V = 2.7V max output. Yikes! Too low!

(To be specific, the NodeMCU board you linked to will operate only if 3.3V is provided directly OR a voltage greater than **4.3V** is applied to the VIN pin)

**Use a low-dropout regulator**

Thankfully some semiconductor companies make special regulators with ultra-low **dropout voltages** for cases like this. You can buy an LM3940 ([datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3940.pdf)) from [Digi-Key for $1.66](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/LM3940IT-3.3-NOPB/LM3940IT-3.3-NOPB-ND/308006), or you could try getting free samples directly from Texas Instruments [here](http://www.ti.com/product/LM3940/samplebuy).

That unit has a drop voltage of only 0.2V when the NodeMCU is drawing ~320mA. According to [this thread](http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=3875), the ESP8266 draws 320mA at most, and this occurs only during startup.

If using this method, connect the 3.3V output of your new, fancy regulator to the 3.3V pin on your NodeMCU.

**Alternative to buying another regulator**:

I found [this module on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MG1LEU2) which **looks** like an original NodeMCU ESP12 board. According to the [NodeMCU's schematic](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-devkit/master/Documents/NODEMCU_DEVKIT_SCH.png), the original boards use a [SPX3819](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/146/SPX3819_DS_R200_082312-17072.pdf) regulator which has a **dropout voltage** of 0.34V (and would work for you).

A word of caution: people can easily build and sell "fakes" or "clones" that **look** similar but are made with cheaper components with different operating characteristics. It is difficult to tell from the picture, but since the module only costs $8.99 it might be worth it to buy and test one anyway.